# Only show a menu under Unity

Tags: unity, python, application-development, appmenu

We want our app [Nitro](http://nitrotasks.com) to be more native on Ubuntu. We're going to do this by adding Unity quicklist support & appmenu support.

Is it possible for the app to only utilize the app menu? If the user is not using Unity they won't get any menu bar. The only reason why we want the menu to be in the Ubuntu version is for the sake of desktop integration.

Comment: Normally ,If you included a normal menu in the app ,unity will converted it into  appmenu and other de will place the menu in the app itself ,

Comment: Yes, but we don't want the menu in the app itself. Only under unity.

Comment: You mean it wont support other DE LIKE GNOME SHELL and xfce?

Comment: In Gnome Shell it will use the Gnome Shell App Menu. The app doesn't need menus - it's fine how it is. We just want them for the sake of integration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, certainly that's not a normal use case :-)  So there are a couple of ways to do things.  What the Chrome developers have done is create the menu bar but leave it hidden, it gets picked up by appmenu-gtk but isn't shown.

Another option is to just look for the `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` environment variable.  If it is set, then you can build the menu bar, if not, don't build it.

Hope that helps,